# simple javascript unit converter & calculator

Tags: javascript, html

My friend is selling coffee beans & wants to have a basic calculator so customers know how many beans they need to buy. He wants a form with two fields:

> To make *_*_ [g/oz] of coffee
>
> Grind *_*_ [g/oz/lbs] of beans

COFFEE_OUT=15xBEANS_IN but there is also some unit conversion here. He wants each field to reflect changes in the other fields, with no SUBMIT button. What's the simplest way to do this? The HTML will look something like this, right?

```
<form action="">
    I want to make 
    <input type="text" name="COFFEE_OUT"> 
    <select>
        <option value="g">g</option>
        <option value="oz">oz</option>
    </select>
    of coffee --- I'll need to grind
    <input type="text" name="BEANS_IN"> 
    <select>
        <option value="g">g</option>
        <option value="oz">oz</option>
        <option value="lb">lb</option>
    </select>
    beans
</form>
```

But what should the javascript look like?

Can you think of any examples of something like this? Even most tutorial calculators and unit converters that I see are much more complicated, this is a basic but very specific use & I can't recall seeing something exactly like it anywhere.

Comment: use blur, change event for input as well as select...

Comment: on key up,key down,key press,onblur...

Comment: I should have added I am cool with using jquery like Messiah suggested.

Answer (score 3):

[Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/G8vMd/5/)

```
$('input').on("keyup",function () {
    $("#result").val(parseInt($("#amount").val(), 10)*  15);
});
```

Comment: Oh this looks and works nicely but how can I get it to convert the units?

Comment: what unit conversion are we talking about.Its not that difficult.just basic math.unit form can be converted in to other..$ to other currency??what unit??

Comment: So if a user changes OZ to g, the math will update to give them the proper answer for the amount they have filled in.

Comment: no no...you have to code for that...provide multiple conditons..nothing happens autonmatically!!!